# Vue JS issue with v-bind

Tags: vue.js

I m working in application VUE js and have an issue with a variable type data called currentValue, this is not updating in the view when the modal popup shows, only is retrieving the first record, but in the console, I can see the variable with the changed value? Anyone can help?

Here is my html

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="actions-measures">
  <div>
    <a  class="btn-status"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" 
      aria-expanded="false">...</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="options-status">
      <a class="dropdown-item"  v-on:click="showModal()" >Change Status</a>
    </div>
    <modal-patient-status
      v-bind:med="currentValue">
    </modal-patient-status>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: You must show more code, what's `currentValue` being used for? when is it changing?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `this.$forceUpdate();` in the `showModal` function to force update the DOM to view the changes